# How to skip child node within parent node(Xpath)

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<div id="blurb">
   Software Quality Assurance &amp; Testing Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers. Join them; it only takes a minute:
   <br>
   <br>
   <a href="/users/signup?ssrc=hero&amp;returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fsqa.stackexchange.com%2f" id="tell-me-more" class="button">Join</a>
</div>
```

I have above HTML markup. I need to extract below text from parent tag **div** node excluding its child nodes:

> Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers. Join them; it only takes a minute:

But, the `xpath` I am using is extracting `Join` also, from child node `<a>`.

Below is the `xpath` I tried:

`//div[@id='blurb']/*[not(@id='tell-me-more')]`

How would I write `xpath` to extract text from parent node only and not from its child nodes?

Comment: Your problem falls more in the data-manipulation/assertion side, and less on the **why isn't this working with Selenium** side. Just treat the text via a `.contains()`, or `.include()` assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use `//div[@id='blurb']/text()[1]`, but `selenium` doesn't support this syntax as `XPath` should return `WebElement` only, not text nodes...

You can get required output using `JavaScriptExecutor`:

```
WebElement myDiv = driver.findElement(By.id("blurb"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String divText = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;", myDiv);
```

Comment: if by same logic, I want to get test value of <a>; what should be childnode's value?

Comment: Child node of `a` is link text. Also anchor element could contain `span`...

Comment: can in not change childNodes[0] to childNodes[3] as <a> tag is a child of <div> tag and get the text value?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get text from `<a>` in the same way?

Comment: `WebElement` selectors should be short and simple, not clunky and prone to change. He should really just assert/manipulate the data he gets from the `div#blubr` container and that's it. I know his question stated he wants the text w/o the `<a>`, but using `Executor` for something that should be simple is blatantly overkill and not a best-practice.

Comment: @iamdanchiv `By.id("blurb")` is short and simple selector as much as possible. I've already clarified why OP couldn't use just `XPath` to solve the problem. If you find simpler solution then let me know

Comment: @Andersson : yes; but starting from <div> element

Comment: @kushal. In this case `return arguments[0].childNodes[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue` should return link text - `"Join"`. Here we need to find child node `<a>` (the 6th child node of `<div>`) and get the first child node of `<a>` which is text node `"Join"`

Comment: @kushal., 1st child node is text, that OP wants to get, 2nd- is `<br>`, 3rd is new line character `"\n"`, 4th- again `<br>`, 5th- one more `"\n"`, 6th- `<a>`

Comment: @Andresson : thanks for the clarification, I wasn't takming "\n" into consideration. Cheers!!

Comment: But it returned nothing

Comment: Are you sure you test it with provided exact piece of `HTML`? Works well for me...

Comment: Thanks got it now; i hadn't added `childNodes[0]`, I suppose we can't directly use `childNodes[5].nodeValue`

Comment: That will return nothing as `childNodes[5]` is a web-element `<a>`, but not some kind of value which can be returned as string. You can also use `childNodes[5].tagName` to check that

Comment: @Andersson - The xpath worked. But I was trying through xpath, and thanks for explanation as why it would not work using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer using below xpath and it worked:-

```
//div[@id='blurb']/*[not(self::a)]
```

Here, we are omitting inner anchor tag **a** inside parent **div** tag